# How to create a i18n web application in netbeans 12?

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications

I create a web application in netbenas 12 and I try to do basic stuff for i18n. The structure of my project is:
[image]

In the `TestDriver.java` I have the following code:

```
public class TestDriver {

public static void main(String [] args){
    String lang = "fr";
    String country = "FR";
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang, country);
    
    ResourceBundle myBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("demo.test", locale);
    String key = myBundle.getString("wish");
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

}

When I execute this class using right click>run file i get the following error:

```
    -----------------------< com.mycompany:demoI18n >-----------------------
Building demoI18n 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ demoI18n ---
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name demo.test, locale fr_FR
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:932)
    at i18n.TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:24)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  3.097 s
Finished at: 2021-10-11T23:23:30-04:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project demoI18n: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I dont know how to solve this error. ANY SUGGESTION?

Answer (score 0):

Download and unzip the InternationalizeDemo.zip project to any location on your computer.

Choose File > Open Project, navigate to the InternationalizeDemo project that you extracted in the last step, and click Open. The project folder might be in a containing folder that is also called InternationalizeDemo .

Expand Source Packages > Demo and double-click FindDialog.java . The sample form opens in the GUI Builder.

To download it refer to this official documentation-https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html

Comment: This is not an answer because it ignores the OP's problem, which is a `MissingResourceException` when calling `getBundle()`. Recommending a tutorial is fine as a comment, but answers should directly address the issue raised in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem with a Maven project in NetBeans, but if I create an Ant project instead it works fine. Therefore, the issue is not with your Java code, but with the Maven configuration.

You get the `MissingResourceException` because the properties files in your **demo** directory are not being copied to the `target` directory during the Maven build process. You can see this if you build the project, then click the **Files** tab and expand the `target` directory in NetBeans; there are no properties files! This explains the *"Can't find bundle for base name demo.test, locale fr_FR"* error message at the start of the stack trace.

There are multiple approaches to resolve this, but the simplest is to edit **pom.xml** to specify that all properties files under `src/main/java` should be included during the copying phase of the Maven build. Just insert this immediately after the `<build>` tag:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This results in the properties files being copied to `target` during the build process so that they are accessible at runtime:

[image: copyProps]

Then, when you run file **TestDriver.java** everything should work.

See [Including and excluding files and directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-resources-plugin-2.6/examples/include-exclude.html) and [Specifying resource directories](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-resources-plugin-2.6/examples/include-exclude.html) in the Maven documentation for more information.